Prefix and slash separated
I would like to know how to make a command using prefix and another using slash in the same code. There are things that I want to appear only in the slash command, so in this case the hybrid_command doesn't work.
I tried using:
@cog_ext.cog_slash()

but it didn't work

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
